# How to get data from an object array to another object array ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let objArray = [ {value:null} , {value:null}];
let dataArray= [{0:12},{1:23}];
```

How can I get the data from dataArray to assign to 'value' in objArray ? I want to obtain an object array like below:

```
objArray = [{value:12},{value:23}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this.

```js
let objArray = [ {value:null} , {value:null}];
let dataArray= [{0:12},{1:23}];

const result = objArray.map((item, index) => {
  item.value = dataArray[index][index]
  return item;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you want to keep the result in objArray, please assign the result simply ```objArray = objArray.map....```, not using the ```result``` const.

Answer (score 1):

it is pretty simple. You can use assign property values of dataArray to objArray.

```
objArray[0].value = dataArray[0][0]; //Note: I used bracket notation instead of dot (.) notation for accessing objects in dataArray
objArray[1].value = dataArray[1][1];
```

You can also iterate (loop) through arrays to assign values, but let it be practice for yourself to learn.

Good luck!